# How can my Javascript shopping cart code be improved? Please forgive the raw code

Tags: javascript, performance, shopping-cart

In the last few days I have tried to get my head around Javascript. This is my first proper Javascript and I am wondering if anybody can see anyways that I can improve my code and ultimately my knowledge of Javascript. I appreciate my code thus far may seem a bit raw.

One thing I am stumped at how to finish my 'calcUnitPriceF' function so that I am not creating an array in each product case. These prices will come from a database soon.

The code below I hope is very clear in what it does.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function update(){

var total = 0.00;
var calcUnitPrice, quantity;

var myForm = document["getElementById"]("totalform");
var justQuantity = myForm["quantity[]"];
var justPrice = myForm["productPrice[]"];
var unitPrice = myForm["unitPrice[]"];
var linePrice = myForm["linePrice[]"];

for(var i =0; i < justQuantity.length; i++)
{
 justQuantity[i].value = Math.floor(justQuantity[i].value);
 quantity = justQuantity[i].value;
 calcUnitPrice = 0;

 if(isNaN(quantity) || quantity < 0) {
   justQuantity[i].value ="0";
 }
 else
 {
  calcUnitPrice = calcUnitPriceF(justPrice[i].value,quantity);

  document.getElementById('unitPrice[' + i + ']').innerHTML = '£' + calcUnitPrice.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('linePrice[' + i + ']').innerHTML = '£' + (calcUnitPrice * justQuantity[i].value).toFixed(2); 
  total = (total + (quantity* calcUnitPrice));
 }
}

document.getElementById("delivery").innerHTML = "Your Order Delivery is: £2.50";
document.getElementById("Totprice2").innerHTML = "Your Order Total is: £" + total.toFixed(2);

}

function calcUnitPriceF(product,quantity)
{
 switch(product)
  {
   case '0':
    return 0;
   case '1':
    var values = [5, 4 , 15.30 , 10 , 12 ]; // Structure(Exceeding Quantity Price,Quantity Under, Price)

    for(var i = 1; i< values.length; i=i+2)
     if(quantity < values[i])
      return values[i+1];
    return values[0];
   case '2':
    return 75;
   }
}
</script>

<body>

<form id="totalform">
<select id ="productPrice[]" onchange="update()">
  <option value="0">Please Select One</option>
  <option value="1">Product 1</option>
  <option value="2">Product 2</option>
</select>
QUANTITY <input type = "text" id = "quantity[]" onChange="update()" >
UNIT PRICE <p id="unitPrice[0]" style="display:inline;">£0.00</p>
LINE PRICE <p id="linePrice[0]" style="display:inline;">£0.00</p><br />

<select id="productPrice[]" onchange="update()">
  <option value="0">Please Select One</option>
  <option value="1">Product 1</option>
  <option value="2">Product 2</option>
</select>
QUANTITY <input type = "text" id = "quantity[]" onChange="update()" >
UNIT PRICE <p id="unitPrice[1]" style="display:inline;">£0.00</p>
LINE PRICE <p id="linePrice[1]" style="display:inline;">£0.00</p><br />

<span id ="delivery">Your Order Delivery is: £0.00</span><br />
<span id ="Totprice2">Your Order Total is: £0.00</span>
</form>
```

Comment: If I only have 1 product line(One block of HTML) in the cart, this does not work.

Comment: Define improvement. You can improve your code in several ways, e.g. you could improve it for human readablity or for performance.

Comment: Improvement defined: To see where I can improve my Javascript skill set. Like I said this is my first attempted at something in Javascript and I want to improve.

Comment: @alex23: I will be doing proper checking in my PHP. This is just for the 'front end show'.

Comment: @alex23 any idea when I only have one row of HTML for the products this code does not work?

Answer (score 1):

The number one thing I would do is change the JS approach.

```
var project = {};
project.ShoppingCart = function() {
    this.total = 0;
    this.justQuantity = ...;
    this.currentQuantity = 0;
};
/**
 * Updates the current quantity in the shopping cart.
 * @param {!number} quantity The quantity to update with.
 * @return {void} nothing.
 */
project.ShoppingCart.prototype.updateQuantity = function(quantity) {
    // this is how to check for a number properly.
    if (!isNaN(quantity) && parseFloat(quantity) && isFinite(quantity)) {
        this.currentQuantity = quantity;
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid quantity");
    };
};
```

Now in order to use the above.

```
var shoppingCart = new project.ShoppingCart();
```

Look at Object Oriented Javascript, how to properly use that, stop poluting the global namespace and randomly writing functions, comment your code and validate things properly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in this direction. I shall take this route now. Is this not overkill? All I want to do is what I have achieved: Update prices of products and delievery/total.

Comment: Thanks. I have not found a good JS resource to be honest with you. I have resorted to watching some videos the guy who made it yahoo. But I find it much easier to read and learn than watch and learn. I tend to flick over to w3schools but that is very basic. I have got the 6th edition Orielly book now which I will chew through.